# Heroku App trouble with pg in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, gemfile, heroku-postgres

I have a Heroku app/RoR server set. When trying to run the command

`bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate`

I get a `LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.1/pg_ext`?

I have this in my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'puma'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Not sure where I am going wrong...

I think I go wrong in that I am not setting up the `SET DATABASE_URL=postgres:///$(whoami)` correctly, what is the format for this command?

I get a different error after trying some things now:

`rake aborted! PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password provided`

Where do I have to provide this password?

Answer (score 1):

I use PostgreSQL at Heroku and SQLite for local development. If you rely on some Postgres specific features then it's probably not your case. Otherwise it can be good enough.

Here's a part from my Gemfile:

```
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development

# Deploy on Heroku
gem 'pg', group: :production
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Comment: I use PostgreSQL in dev and prod. so that I'm testing the actual db I will be using in production. Mixing dbs development to production seems to introduce a variable that is unnecessary. IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You have this listed as the command you ran that generated the error. This is not a valid command line:

```
bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
```

These are 2 discrete actions. To create the database, first time, start with:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

On subsequent updates to the database use:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Ah was just attempting to follow the instructions provided from Heroku. Thank you.

Comment: Even with using them separately; I still get the same error.

Comment: In your example Gemfile, the ruby gem itself is not included. The ruby gem should be the first line after the rubygems.org line.

Comment: I'm not sure which platform you're developing on, but where I develop, the Heroku rake invoke is:  heroku run rake db:migrate. More things to try.